# React - event listeners collision

Tags: reactjs, events, keydown

I have a component which shows a modal when you press `'Enter'`. It works cool.

I'd like to add keyboard interactions to the modal. And everything was going cool **UNTIL** I selected `'Enter'` as the confirmation button in the modal.

Which is my problem? The enter is the used key to show the modal when you are in the component. But, also, it's the confirmation key when you are in the modal.

It sounds good. BUT the problem is the pressed 'enter' from the component is also caught by my modal (in the `window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyPress);`) in it's first cycle.

So, it started and hide in the same moment and I can't interact with it. A suggestion or workaround for it?

**Hint**:

I have tried adding a `timeOut` of 500 milliseconds in my `modal.componentDidMount.addEventListener`. BUT the problem is it's related to the computer and not a deterministic behavior. I'd to assure the correct behavior in any case.

Also, my code looks like:

**0. modal.jsx**

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
  //...
  onKeyPress (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      this.props.hideScroll();
    }
  }

  // MY PROBLEM (I think so)
  componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onKeyPress);
  }

  render () {
    return <div>Cool Modal</div>;
  }
}
```

**1. component.jsx**

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  //...
  onKeyPress (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      this.setState({
        showModal: true
      });      
    }
  }

  render () {
    let modal = this.state.showModal && <Modal hideScroll={this.hideScroll} />
    return (
      {modal}
      <input onKeyDown={this.onKeyPress}>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event.stopPropagation should do the work.? Seems like react is so damn fast (capturing event in component is changing the state) which renders modal. and after it renders it gets the same event which was captured in component (basically). Actually it is synthetic event on component level (wrapper at the top of native event)

Comment: It was fast. I was still writing a code in sandbox to be able to share and test for other users! But It solved my problem! (thanks)